# Bayes analysis as used in a Presidential Election - with calculations shown

Tags: probability, education

Can you show all the steps needed for a Bayesian probability progression as new information is received.  As an example, initial estimate for Obama to win (popular vote) is 55%.  In state-A, Democrats usually get 51.5% of the vote but receive 57% of the vote after 10% of the ballots have been counted.  In state-B,Democrats receive 48% 0f the vote after 5% of of the ballots have been counted.

3 or 4 new pieces of data come in from other states (your choice of numbers).

What I am interested in are the calculations one goes through to get the final probability estimate.

I want to display this to 15 - 16 year old high school students.

Thank you for any help that you can give me.

Comment: Sheldon, if you're interested, please take a look at my Q on [Bayesian prediction of SuperBowl Coin toss](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49202/bayesian-prediction-of-superbowl-coin-toss). Unfortunately the Q was closed but I assure you the computations are correct. In fact I will reword it and ask a similar Q in the near future.